# Direct Sum of Sub modules and proof Verification

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, modules, module-isomorphism

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $N_{1},N_{2}$ be submodules of $M$ such that $M = N_{1}\oplus N_{2}$. Then $M/N_{1}\simeq N_{2}$ and $M/N_{2}\simeq N_{1}$.

**My Attempt:**

> Define a $R$-module Homomorphism $\varphi:M\rightarrow N_{2}$ given by
>   $\varphi ((n_{1},n_{2}))=n_{2}$.
>
> Clearly, $\varphi$ is a surjective $R$-module Homomorphism and kernel
>   of $\varphi$ is $N_{1}$ because for all elements of the form
>   $(n_{1},0)$ have their image $0$ under $\varphi$.
>
> Therefore, by *First Isomorphism Theorem for Modules*, We have
>   $$M/N_{1}\simeq N_{2}$$

---

Can anyone spot my mistake and please give me hints to correct it and solve the question?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Question is: Is my proof correct? and if no, please provide a solution otherwise, a different proof which is more elegant than mine.

Comment: Your prove is perfect and it is elegant